# when trying to join three tables returning duplicate entries in mysql

Tags: mysql

Please dont be soo hard on me, Im new at this.
I have three tables, the table configuration is as bellow. the data in the tables are coming through API.

```
cms:

user_id | C_ID | B_Name | summary_no | summary_count
--------+------+--------+------------+--------------+
2       | 1    | SC Bank| 1          | 3            |
--------+------+--------+------------+--------------+

summary_count:

id      | C_ID | total_cheque| total_amount 
--------+------+-------------+---------------+
1       | 1    | 1           | 5000          | 
--------+------+-------------+---------------+
2       | 1    | 2           | 6000          |
--------+------+-------------+---------------+
3       | 1    | 1           | 7000          |
--------+------+-------------+---------------+

Images:

Img_ID  | C_ID | Image           |
--------+------+-----------------+
1       | 1    | download.jpg    |
--------+------+-----------------+
2       | 1    | download(1).jpg |
--------+------+-----------------+
3       | 1    | download(2).jpg |
--------+------+-----------------+
4       | 1    | download(4).jpg |
--------+------+-----------------+
```

so the logic is if the summary_count in the cms table is 3 then there would be 3 records inserted into summary_count table with same C_ID. The same thing would happen in images table but, the number of images could varry.

So I tried the below query to get the values from the tables.

```
SELECT * FROM cms
INNER JOIN summary_count ON summary_count.C_ID = cms.C_ID
INNER JOIN images ON images.C_ID = cms.C_ID
```

I've tried some other combinations as well but gives me the same output.

The output I'm getting is

[output of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioBhg.png)

is there any possible way I can get a output like below

[required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S25m.png)

Comment: Your schema is missing a foreign key from `images` to `summary_count` (or vice versa) otherwise there's nothing to tie a row in `summary_count` to a specific row in `images`, resulting in the output you got.

Comment: Actually **summary_count** and **images** are child tables of **cms** table. the foreign key is given to **C_ID** of both the tables.

Comment: Yes, but without a key to tie `summary_count` records to specific `images` records, which is implied by your desired output, you get the cartesian product of all summary/image records for every `C_ID`.